# A bit confused with hyperlinks... [HTML]

Tags: html, hyperlink

I recently began construction of my first website, I'm still a beginner in html. My site has three buttons on the side, "Games", "Chat", and "About". They all have custom pictures, but it seems like there is a very small hyperlinked "-" in the bottom right of the button. Like a hyperlink, it turns red when clicked. Here is a picture of my clicking the "Games" button: [As you can see, there is a small "-" hyperlink on the bottom right of the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmLuO.png)

Here is ALL my code for the games page:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>CBgames.com</title>
    </header>
    <body bgcolor=#474747 text=#FFFFFF>
        <center>
            <img src="siteimages/title.gif">
        </center>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/games.html">
            <img src="siteimages/gamesbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseovergamesbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/gamesbutton.gif'" />
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/chat.html">
            <img src="siteimages/chatbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoverchatbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/chatbutton.gif'" />
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/about.html">
            <img src="siteimages/aboutbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoveraboutbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/aboutbutton.gif'" >
        </a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table Align="left" Border="1" Width="300">
            <tr>
                <td><center>Our Newest Games:</center></TD>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>Game</center>
                    <center>Game</center>
                    <center>Game</center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin:0px;
                padding-bottom:25px;
            }
            #footer {
                color:white;
                font:George, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size:16px;
                width:1920px;
                height:20px;
                line-height:20px;
                background-color:#474747;
                text-align:center;
                position:fixed;
                bottom:0px;
            }
        </style>
        <head>
            <body>
                <div id="footer">
                    COPYRIGHT &copy; 2015 CB-GAMES.NET [SA] - ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
                </div>
            </body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm still a newbie at this, sorry for any troubles.

Comment: Your use of ALL CAPS tag names, layout tables, lack of Doctype, presentational markup and various errors that [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) would pick up suggest that you have found an HTML tutorial from around 1997. I suggest you look for something more modern.

Comment: You have to learn basic stuffs first. Here you have lots of basic errors like you are using two body tags, wrong <head> tag. At first clear your very basic html structure. You can learn from here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction

Comment: I edited the question to be properly tabbed and have only lowercase tags to improve readability. @Blake, you should use lowercase stuff in html tags.

Comment: @JCOC611 I used the code you edited, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Edits aren't meant to fix your code, just make it easier for people to read

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for adding a URL in HTML

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

An example of adding "Example" website URL would be like the following

```
<a href="http://example.com">Click here to direct to Example site</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces between the start tag for the anchor and the image inside of it (and between the image and the end tag).

Spaces are text.

Text in a link gets underlined.

Reformat your HTML to remove the spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by "You have spaces between the start tag for the anchor and the image inside of it"?

Comment: Any new lines, spaces or tabs are considered whitespace.  At the end of `...html">` you have a new line and then some spaces or tabs before `<img src="site...`.  This is considered normal text which, based on your stylesheet gets underlined because it is a hypertext link (inside an A tag).  Try reformatting as follows... `games.html"><img` (followed by new line) then `src="...`.

Answer (score 0):

There is still an awful lot wrong with your markup but here is a quick attempt of moving you along in the right direction:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CBgames.com</title>
        <style type="text/stylesheet">
        BODY { 
            background-color:#474747; 
            color:#FFF;
            margin:0;
            padding-bottom:25px;
            }
        .titleimage { text-align:center; }
        .buttons {
            margin-bottom: 2em;
        }
        .buttons A { display:block; }
        .table1 { text-align:left; border:solid 1px #000; width: 300px; }
        #footer {
                color:white;
                font:George, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size:16px;
                height:20px;
                line-height:20px;
                background-color:#474747;
                text-align:center;
                position:fixed;
                left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
            }       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dIv class="titleimage"><img src="siteimages/title.gif"></div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="games.html"><img 
                src="siteimages/gamesbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseovergamesbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/gamesbutton.gif'" /></a>
            <a href="chat.html"><img 
                src="siteimages/chatbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoverchatbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/chatbutton.gif'" /></a>
            <a href="about.html"><img 
                src="siteimages/aboutbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoveraboutbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/aboutbutton.gif'" ></a>
        <div>

        <table class="table1">
            <tr><td>Our Newest Games:</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>Game</div>
                    <div>Game</div>
                    <div>Game</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <footer id="footer">
           COPYRIGHT &copy; 2015 CB-GAMES.NET [SA] - ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```